# how to write translations to file

Tags: php, content-management-system, prestashop

I want to make my site multi langueage. I have seen in packages like prestashop, the translations are saved to a file like this:

```
<?php
$_lang['contact_header_steps']      = "Order whatever you like in 4 easy steps";
$_lang['contact_steps_1']           = "Fill out the form";
$_lang['contact_steps_2']           = "We will send you a payment link";
$_lang['contact_steps_3']           = "Pay online";
$_lang['contact_steps_3a']          = "";
?>
```

so this is what I did. I work with smarty and in my templates i use (expample): {$LANG.contact_header_steps}

and i use a global detection that stores the slected language in a cookie so my site knows wich language to show.

All work fine but now i want to build a easy management system.

I want to write to this file (like mentioned above) from the admin (without DB). I have seen this in prestashop but after looking in to the core i just got lost.

so when i open the translation page it must read this file and create 2 input fields. when i save it must save to this file

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give every language a 'code name' ex: English:en ; France:fr ; etc.

Assuming you stored the language in cookie $_COOKIE['lang']

```
<?php
    $mylang = $_COOKIE['lang'];     //get the cookie

    //define the translation here
    $_lang['en']['contact_header_steps'] = "Order whatever you like in 4 easy steps";
    $_lang['en']['contact_steps_1']      = "Fill out the form";
    $_lang['en']['contact_steps_2']      = "We will send you a payment link";
    $_lang['en']['contact_steps_3']      = "Pay online";
    $_lang['en']['contact_steps_3a']     = "";

    $_lang['fr']['contact_header_steps'] = "OTHER_LANG";
    $_lang['fr']['contact_steps_1']      = "THAT_I";
    $_lang['fr']['contact_steps_2']      = "HAVE_NO";
    $_lang['fr']['contact_steps_3']      = "IDEA_OF";
    $_lang['fr']['contact_steps_3a']     = "HERE";

    echo $_lang[$mylang]['contact_header_steps']; //use it to call the language

?>
```

Comment: That is undrtstand so far. But how can i add new translations so save to file from admin so That i Dont have to edit the file

Comment: @rZaaaa use require_once(). On index.php `<?php include_once('langs.php'); ?>` Then insert all translations on langs.php